# Why I can't pass middleware('auth:api') and get {"message":"Unauthenticated."} although I send correct personal access token?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

Headers:
Content-Type: application/json,
Accept: application/json,
Authorization: Bearer (exact_token_without semicolon or anything else)

Here is my AuthController and I can login to it.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:55',
            'email' => 'email|required|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed'
        ]);

        $validatedData['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);

        $user = User::create($validatedData);

        $accessToken = $user->createToken('Auth Token')->accessToken;
        return response([ 'user' => $user, 'access_token' => $accessToken]);
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $loginData = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'email|required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if (!auth()->attempt($loginData)) {
            return response(['message' => 'Invalid Credentials']);
        }

        $accessToken = auth()->user()->createToken('Auth Token')->accessToken;

        return $accessToken;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://mobiosolutions.com/how-to-create-rest-api-in-laravel-6-using-passport/ I have done this 3 days ago with the help of this blog post.follow step by step of this

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't even say how to pass middleware